# ATM code chef question if - else condition problem in python

Tags: python

```
a, b = input().split()
c = int(a)
d = float(b)
e = format(d, ".2f")

if c % 5 == 0:
    f = d - c - 0.50
    print(format(f, ".2f"))
elif c % 5 != 0:
    print(e)
elif c > d:
    print(e)
else:
    print(e)
```

1. here if you take input of 30 120.00 then 1st if condition will do it
2. 2nd elif will see if the first int input is not multiple of 5 (which is 30 in above 1st point) then give out put of balance which is 120.00
3. but i am having issue with 3rd condition where i am not trying to do if inputted amount of withdrawal is larger then balance then we should show balance as output (ex: 300 120.00 output 120.00)
   https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST
4. above is link to question which i am trying to solve just refer it also once.

Comment: Only the first two conditions can ever be reached: either `c` is a multiple of 5, or it is not a multiple of 5: there is no third choice.  The `c > d` test would have to go first to be meaningful.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Just a practical comment to keep your variable names clear and avoid proliferation: since the CodeChef statement calls them x, y, why not call them x,y here too instead of a,b? Next, since all you ever do with them is convert them: `c = int(a); d = float(b)` it's much clearer to reuse the names `x = int(x); y = float(y)` . Last, there's absolutely no need to declare `e = format(d, ".2f")`, just use an f-string when you print it: `print(f'{y:.2f}')`. Likewise, you don't need to declare `f = d - c - 0.50`. Please read any of the many good tutorials on using f-strings.

Comment: This may all sound trivial but it really aids debuggability to keep a problem of two variables a problem of two variables, not make six. Also, it makes it easier to compare your solution to others on CodeChef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have got confused with the if-elif control structure

If there are if and then elif statement then the control will go to the first statement that satisfies the example

Here, if first 'if' statement is not true eventually the second becomes true and control will never go to the third statement.

You can try this solution instead

```
a=int(a)
b=float(b)
if (a%5!=0)
    print(format(b, ".2f"))
else:
    if a+0.5>b:
        print(format(b, ".2f"))
    else:
        print(format(b-a-0.50,'.2f'))
```

This concept I used here is called nested if-else loops

Comment: First I initialized the variables

Checked if the number 'a' is not divisible by 5 then directly print the second number 'b' directly

Else a+0.5(charge) is greater than b then cannot withdraw and print b as it is

if all the above statement are false then money can be withdrawed and transaction takes place